# Custom returnUrl on Node.js Passport's Google strategy

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Express and Passport OpenID Google strategy and I would like to set returnURL on each auth request to be able to return to the page that initiated that auth.

The situation is that I have HTML5 slides application with Node.js backend (and with social stuff and editor and Portal and extensions... https://github.com/bubersson/humla) and I want be able to log in user on some slide (via slide menu...) but then I want him to get back to same slide easily.

So I would need something like this?

```
app.get('/auth/google', function(req,res) {
   var cust = "http://localhost:1338/"+req.params.xxx;
   passport.authenticate('google', returnURL:cust, function ...
}
```

I've read Passport's guide, but still don't know how to do that. I know this wouldn't be safe, but how else could I do it?

Or how can I make the application to return to the page from where the login has been initiated? Or is there a way to make OpenID authentication using AJAX (and still be able to use passport as well)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've figured this out for my apps Twitter authentication, I am sure that the GoogleStrategy is quite similar.  Try a variant of this:

Assuming you have defined the route for the callback from the authentication service like so (from the passport guide):

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback',
  passport.authenticate('twitter', {
      successRedirect: authenticationRedirect(req, '/account')
    , failureRedirect: '/'
  })
);
```

Just change that block to this:

```
app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', function(req, res, next){
  passport.authenticate('twitter', function(err, user, info){
    // This is the default destination upon successful login.
    var redirectUrl = '/account';

    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { return res.redirect('/'); }

    // If we have previously stored a redirectUrl, use that, 
    // otherwise, use the default.
    if (req.session.redirectUrl) {
      redirectUrl = req.session.redirectUrl;
      req.session.redirectUrl = null;
    }
    req.logIn(user, function(err){
      if (err) { return next(err); }
    });
    res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

Now, define your middleware for authenticated routes to store the original URL in the session like this:

```
ensureAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }

  // If the user is not authenticated, then we will start the authentication
  // process.  Before we do, let's store this originally requested URL in the
  // session so we know where to return the user later.

  req.session.redirectUrl = req.url;

  // Resume normal authentication...

  logger.info('User is not authenticated.');
  req.flash("warn", "You must be logged-in to do that.");
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

Works!

Comment: This works perfectly, but on redirect it appears to be missing the hash parameters if the user is sent away to authenticate and comes back.  Might there be some way to keep those in the URL when redirecting after logging in?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124932/passport-js-express-js-forward-user-to-original-destination-after-authenticati

Comment: @user645715 maybe try to use `req.session.redirectUrl = req.originalUrl;` instead or `req.url`

Answer (score 16):

Wherever you have your login button, append the request's current URL as a
query parameter (adjust for whatever templating system you use):

```
<a href='/auth/google?redirect=<%= req.url %>'>Log In</a>
```

Then, add middleware to your `GET /auth/google` handler that stores this value in
`req.session`:

```
app.get('/auth/google', function(req, res, next) {
  req.session.redirect = req.query.redirect;
  next();
}, passport.authenticate('google'));
```

Finally, in your callback handler, redirect to the URL stored in the session:

```
app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google',
  failureRedirect: '/'
), function (req, res) {
  res.redirect(req.session.redirect || '/');
  delete req.session.redirect;
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without sessions?

Answer (score 5):

Try `res.redirect('back');` in the callback for `passport.authenticate`

Comment: Ha thanks! Apparently the back route is set between the first and the second OpenID request. I didn't know that! Thanks

Comment: Well I found a problem with this. It works only if I'm already logged in using Google. If passport redirects to the Google page and then returns back to my site - the "page" route is lost. Is there other way to force it to return from Google to my location (the page from where the login has been initiated)?

Comment: @bubersson you'd need to use a more proactive approach like the one on the first answer, for that, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 3):

According to the author this isn't possible with OpenID strategies.  We managed to update these dynamically by directly accessing the variables:

```
app.get('/auth/google', function(req, res, next) {
  passport._strategies['google']._relyingParty.returnUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/test';
  passport._strategies['google']._relyingParty.realm = 'http://localhost:3000';
  passport.authenticate('google')(req, res, next);
});
```