# How to redirect to the page from which the user logged in in react-redux app with passport-facebook authentication?

Tags: react-redux, react-router-redux, passport-facebook

I have a react-redux app and use passport-facebook for authentication. I want the user to be able to login from any page of the app and then immediately return (get redirected) to the same page. What's the best-practice way to achieve this?

So far I've come up with the following solution, but it doesn't feel right. I've created a 'dummy' SuccessLogin component and I redirect to that component after successful login. In the 'dummy' component I redirect the user again to the previous location.

Server-side code:

```
router.get '/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/success', failureRedirect: '/auth' })
```

My 'dummy' component looks like this:

```
class SuccessLogin extends React.Component

  componentDidMount: () ->
    @props.redirectBack()

  render: () ->
    null
```

This is how `redirectBack` is defined:

```
redirectBack = () ->
  (dispatch, getState) ->
    dispatch go(-1)
```

`go` is the action creator from React-Router-Redux: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux

Am I going to run into any problems with this solution? What would be a better way to implement this logic?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found a solution that has nothing to do with React-Redux. It is inspired by those two questions: [Redirecting to previous page after authentication in node.js using passport.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335881/redirecting-to-previous-page-after-authentication-in-node-js-using-passport-js) and [how to redirect to original page after successful authentication using passport-google-oauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586774/how-to-redirect-to-original-page-after-successful-authentication-using-passport).
Server-side code:

```
setRedirect = (req, res, next) ->
  req.session.redirectTo = req.headers.referer
  next()

successRedirect = (req, res) ->
  destination = req.session.redirectTo || '/'
  res.redirect(destination)

router.get '/facebook', setRedirect, passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email'] })    
router.get '/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/auth' }), successRedirect
```