# Custom returnURL not passing to Node.js Passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, url-parameters

From the second answer here:
[Custom returnUrl on Node.js Passport's Google strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885711/custom-returnurl-on-node-js-passports-google-strategy)

I'm using a custom URL passed from the front-end like:

```
  <a href="/auth/meetup?redirect=/chat/{{currentChatID}}" class="btn btn-meetup"><span class="fa fa-meetup"></span> Meetup</a>
```

Where the `redirect` parameter is, for example: `?redirect=/chat/room1`

And in Passport:

```
    app.get('/auth/meetup', function(req, res, next) {
      req.session.redirect = req.query.redirect;
      next();
    }, passport.authenticate('meetup'));


    app.get('/auth/meetup/callback', passport.authenticate('meetup', {
      failureRedirect: '/'
    }), function (req, res) {
      res.redirect(req.session.redirect || '/profile/worlds/meetup');
      delete req.session.redirect;
    });
```

The `req.query.redirect` parameter is `undefined` so it won't redirect to the specified redirect URL, how do I pass the URL correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, had to pass the /s in the URL as:

```
href="/auth/meetup?redirect=%2Fchat%2F{{currentChatID}}"
```